# What's the name of my cat?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

```
Do you like "Little Dorrit"? It’s a nice funny book.
I would read, but I lost it, though is hard to overlook. 
Nerdy books don’t inspire you? Then let’s play play a game,
Good old classic’s my favorite, "Space Quest" is the name.
There’s another pastime, three is all that it takes.
Or if you feel like yelling, let’s hike to the caves.
We could go see a drama, weep for poor ol’ Juliet… 
Now the actual question: what’s the name of my cat?
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe your cat's name is

> CHESTER

My reasoning is that

> every one of the first seven lines references a letter of the NATO phonetic alphabet.

**Do you like "Little Dorrit"? It’s a nice funny book.**

> Written by Charles (or CHARLIE I suppose) Dickens.

**I would read, but I lost it, though is hard to overlook.**

> Referencing the Overlook HOTEL from the Shining.

**Nerdy books don’t inspire you? Then let’s play play a game,**

> "play play" sounds like an ECHO.

**Good old classic’s my favorite, "Space Quest" is the name.**

> A game by the company SIERRA.

**There’s another pastime, three is all that it takes.**

> Normally it's "two to TANGO", but there is a movie named "Three to Tango" as well.

**Or if you feel like yelling, let’s hike to the caves.**

> Screaming in a cave will often produce an ECHO.

**We could go see a drama, weep for poor ol’ Juliet…**

> A tragic tale, along with her lover ROMEO.

**Now the actual question: what’s the name of my cat?**
As described above.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed

> That the first letter of each line spell **DINGTOWN**, but I do not know what this means.

Comment: I hope that cat is not near a baseball field...[dingtown](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dingtown)

Comment: Nope. Actually the first letters lined up accidentally that way, but I decided to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Andy Woodhouse because ROMEO starts with Rosemary's nickname, "Ro" and her son was to be the end of civilization or "Omega" aka "O", "Son of Ro, Me the Omega".  The actual Andy Woodhouse was born January 15, 1968 so ECHO using the Pythagorean alpha key is 3586 (3x5=15 and backwards 86 is 1968, the 15th day of 1968). "Space Quest" is references to the movie "The Questor", which is Andy Woodhouse but an android version of him.  Three to Tango is TTT which is a cross and the pi symbol.  Andy's mother was conceived on the 314th day of the year and Andy is playing part of Jesus and is to be put on the cross.  A "T" is a cross.  HOTEL numerically is 86253.  Ignore the 2, just make it a cross.  Again we have '68 and 3x5=15.  CHARLIE is probably reference to Charles Manson who is linked to Rosemary's Baby via the alleged Tate El Cielo murders. The "Little Dorrit" might be a symbolic way of looking at death as a "door" and specifying its a little door, not the World's door, so it's only Andy who dies and the "it" could be the number 92 which would be the last two digits of Andy's number of days old when they plan to execute him.

Comment: „Three to tango“ was actually a confirmation of Half Life 3, but otherwise you’re absolutely right.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site as well as get your 1st badge.